# opengl driver seems to be ridiculously slow from glUnmapBuffer? This can't be right

Tags: opengl

Through visual studio profiling I see that nearly 50% of my program's execution time is spent in KernalBase.dll. What's it doing in there? I don't know, but the main thing calling it is nvoglv64.dll. To my understanding, nvoglv64.dll is the opengl driver. And the main thing that is calling nvoglv64.dll is one of my functions. This is the function.

```
draw() {
    if (mapped)
    {
        mapped = false;
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
        glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
    }
    glBindVertexArray(trianglesVAO); 
    program.bind();
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, ...); 
}
```

The way I use this function is as follows: I asynchronously map a gl buffer to client memory, and fill it up with a large amount of triangles. Then I draw the buffer using the above function. Except, I use two buffers, each frame I swap which one is being drawn with and which one is being written to.

It's suppose to all be asynchronous. Even glunmap and gldrawelements is suppose to be asynchronous, they should just get put in a command queue. What is causing the slow down?

Comment: Are you calling glFinish after completing the second buffer and switching back to the first?

Comment: @Robinson it goes like this: draw buffer, write to other buffer, swap (window) buffers. When you swap the window buffer or whatever you call it, it implicitly calls glfinish (from what i've read). I also put glfinish infront of the swap window buffers just incase and it has no effect.

Comment: I wouldn't do that if the goal here is to keep everything asynchronous. All you're doing is changing when the synchronization happens. You can leave it implicit (the driver does it to prevent memory from being changed mid-frame) or you can map the buffer unsynchronized and implement synchronization yourself (e.g. fence sync object + `glClientWaitSync (...)` or just read/write/draw different ranges of the same buffer each frame). Either way, try to make enough room for 3 separate frames (1 in-flight + 2 pre-rendered) -- I've discussed this in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Through visual studio profiling I see that nearly 50% of my program's execution time is spent in KernalBase.dll. What's it doing in there?

#### Mapping, unmapping and checking the status of memory as you would expect.

If you want everything to truly be asynchronous, and run the risk of clobbering data that has not been rendered yet, you can map unsynchronized buffers (see [`glMapBufferRange (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml)).

Otherwise, there is some internal driver synchronization to prevent you from modifying memory that has not been drawn yet and that is what you are seeing here. You cannot keep everything asynchronous unless you have enough buffers to accommodate every pending frame.

Now, the thing here is what you just described (2 buffers) is not adequate. You need multiple levels of buffers to prevent pipeline stalls - the driver is (usually) allowed to queue up more than 1 frame worth of commands and the CPU will not be allowed to change memory used by any pending frame (the driver will block when you attempt to call `glMapBuffer (...)`) until said frame is finished.

3 buffers is a good compromise; you might still incur synchronization overhead every once in a while if the CPU's > 2 frames ahead of the GPU. This situation (> 2 pre-rendered frames) indicates that you are GPU-bound, and CPU/driver synchronization for 1 frame will not actually change that. So you can probably afford to block the render thread.

Comment: what about if you use glbufferrange with also the invalidate bit? I use that... but now that i think about it, is multi buffering even necessary with that? and if not... why am i still getting slow down. i managed to get the profiler to more specifically tell me that its spending stupid amounts of time on getexitcodethread () , my guess is the driver runs this in a while to wait for a yhread to finish for something

Comment: @Ragdoll: As long as you don't ever need to read the data back, it'll work. You basically tell the driver that every time you map it, you want a different region of memory. The contents will be uninitialized until you write it, but it sounds like that's not an issue here. Have you combined unsynchronized with invalidate?

Comment: @Ragdoll: Also be aware that drivers with "multi-threaded optimization" will try to evaluate certain commands immediately. `glUnmapBuffer (...)` is one such command, it is beneficial to begin the data transfer as soon as that's called instead of queuing it up and waiting around for the GPU to execute all the commands prior to it. One of the many threads drivers create will be busy doing that, and I'd expect that particular thread to be almost entirely kernel-bound. Are you sure you're measuring the correct thread during profiling?

Comment: im measuring correct thread. I tried a new test, I used a stopwatch class to measure the time it takes for the draw() function, the one I listed in code, to run. It's behaving kind of erratically. Sometimes is instantly fast, 0ms. Sometimes it's consistently around 50 ms, sometimes it's only expensive every third frame. There doesn't seem to be a correlation with the size of buffer, however, the speeds only change when I do user input. this is using bufferange and invalidate / async bit

Comment: also, when it's drawing nothing, buffer size is still allocated to fixed constant, but when nothing is put in the buffer, and drawelements is drawing nothing, the speed of the function is actually much slower over all

Comment: I'm certain the slow down is coming from glUnmapBuffer(). If I do nothing but continuously map ONE buffer with invalidate/async bits, and unmap in a loop, and measure the time unmap takes, it's taking 14ms. That's really slow for something that's suppose to be per frame. I don't even write to the buffer in this case. What's the issue? It's like im causing a sync with unmap, that's no excuse for that slowness.

Comment: oh umm, vsync enabled was causing glunmap to be slow when it shouldn't, I think that may have fixed it

Comment: @Ragdoll: Ah. Yeah, the thing you have to keep in mind with V-Sync is that the blocking need not occur at `SwapBufers (...)`. Basically, the driver is going to block any operation that would modify data once the "flip queue" / "pre-rendered frame" limit is hit. So if you've got V-Sync enabled, know that profiling the CPU may give you the wrong impression. New versions of GL have timer queries, which give a much more accurate picture of how long commands are taking.